# Is there any restriction to use bucket url in two websites?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a testing server and live server websites. Also, I have two s3 buckets for testing server and live server accordingly. When I access the s3 url from the testing server with the same access key and secret key it says "403 access denied".

At the live server, it's working fine. Testing and Live server use the same credentials to access the URL, only the bucket name is different.

Comment: If you are receive an Access Denied error, then you should look at the permissions attached to the credentials you are using, and possibly the Bucket Policy on each bucket. By the way, it's probably a bad idea to use the same credentials in both Test & Live since they could accidentally impact each other's resources. Such systems should be totally separate to avoid potential errors.

Comment: It works!. Thank you, John, for your suggestion.